# RSP_K21 (Find Candidates Response) not working in Hapi 2.6

Tags: java, hl7, hapi

Seems the mailing list isn't very active so I figure I'll try here as well.

In 2.5 and lower versions of Hapi, you could get multiple repetitions of the `RSP_K21_QUERY_RESPONSE` from `RSP_K21`. However, in 2.6, you can only get one. The 2.6 spec still indicates you should be able to return multiple responses. How can I replicate the previous functionality or am I stuck at 2.5?

Answer (score 2):

It appears you're correct; the v2.6 doesn't support repetitions of the QUERY_RESPONSE group.

[v2.5 def](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/v25/apidocs/ca/uhn/hl7v2/model/v25/message/RSP_K21.html)

> 7: RSP_K21_QUERY_RESPONSE (a Group object) **optional repeating**

[v2.6 def](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/v26/apidocs/ca/uhn/hl7v2/model/v26/message/RSP_K21.html)

> 8: RSP_K21_QUERY_RESPONSE (a Group object) **optional**

And their respective methods to get the response:

[v2.5 `getQUERY_RESPONSE()`](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/v25/apidocs/ca/uhn/hl7v2/model/v25/message/RSP_K21.html#getQUERY_RESPONSE%28%29)

> Returns the first repetition of QUERY_RESPONSE (a Group object) - creates it if necessary

[v2.6 `getQUERY_RESPONSE()`](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/v26/apidocs/ca/uhn/hl7v2/model/v26/message/RSP_K21.html#getQUERY_RESPONSE%28%29)

> Returns QUERY_RESPONSE (a Group object) - creates it if necessary

The QUERY_RESPONSE hasn't changed in v2.6, other than an optional ARV segment.

I suspect the reason/intent of the change (from repeating to single) is that the QUERY_RESPONSE was already a repeating group of segments. So if there are multiple candidate matches in the response to the query, the v2.6 standard suggests that they simply repeat within, rather than having multiple QUERY_RESPONSES.

In other words, why have a group of groups allowing repeats, when a single group allowing multiples would suffice? When 2+ candidates are available, they all are packaged into the single RSP_K21_QUERY_RESPONSE, and all their PID+PV1+ARV+NK1+QRI segments are bundled within.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I'm still not clear how to reproduce a legitimate message with this code. Examples from the spec clearly show multiple PID+QRI groups. How can this be replicated with 2.6 HAPI? I can't even have repeating PID/QRI segments on a RSP_K21_QUERY_RESPONSE.